# How do I get a URI without inserting data using SQLiteOpenHelper Content Provider? (Android)

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm making an Android app with a MainActivity, Content Provider, and 4 fragments. I need to check if a username and password exist in a SqlLite database and then send the URI of the row with that username and password to a function. However, I don't understand how to access the URI without inserting into the database (which returns a URI of the inserted row). How can I access the URI of an existing row?

Comment: you don't need to use sqlite database for this simple task. you can use sharedpreferance for this and it will be very easy for you.

Comment: show some related code

Answer (score 0):

Many providers allow you to access a single row in a table by appending an ID value to the end of the URI. For example, to retrieve a row whose _ID is 4 from user dictionary, you can use this content URI:

```
val singleUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, 4)
```

It works for all the standardized content providers (at least those provided by Google). It will work for all content providers which follow the design guidelines for content providers backed up by a row-based data store.

See details  [Content provider in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#kotlin)